# ScrollView and CustomView scrolling 

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView defined like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/scrollv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <com.test.myview android android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

And MyView is extended from View.

in MyView I have a Bitmap drawn with scale of 1.5. It seems as the scollview is working fine since the fading edges appear when I scroll up or down, but then the Image that is drawn in onDraw() (as drawBitmap(bm..)), is not scrolled to show the 'hidden' parts .. it scrolls for 2px's and then stops.. when it gets to onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) - I get that all of the values are 0 there.. I even try to explicitly set the scroll with scollTo or scrollBy methods, no help. So I suppose it's the content that I am mistakening somehow...

Am I doing something wrong? The CustomView I use is basic View with more or less of the common methods overriden (onMeasure, onDraw, onTouchEvent...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a fixed width and height for your custom view.

Comment: ok I figured it out, thanks. But now when I scale the image I suppose I need to reset the size of the scrollview, actually of the parent of myview right? And how do I do that...?

Comment: No, just control the size of your custom view. The ScrollView will take care of itself.

Comment: Nope it doesn't. After I scale the Bitmap, the size of the ScrollView is the initial one and I get only few pixels available to scroll (i.e. if the initial size was 600x1400, after I scale the Bitmap the size of the ScrollView is again 600x1400 and I cannot scroll the Bitmap)..

Comment: Right, but is the custom view itself changing in size?

Comment: after I scale the image (canvas.scale()) I call measure(getWidth()*scaleFactor, getHeight()*scaleFactor) and it goes into onMeasure where I call setMeasuredDimensions(w,h) but again, after that, the size of my view is again the same as before...

Comment: I think setMeasuredDimension doesn't change the actual dimensions, just the recorded dimensions. Use setLayoutParams instead.

Comment: Now I noticed the setScaleX and setScaleY ... and I use 3.0> Android .. is this what I actually need? Will setScaleX(1.3) put a scalefactor of the size of the View by 1.3 ?

Comment: Yes you can use this, remember to use setScaleY as well.